# C# Loop executes for some variables from taken from SQL then fails

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ssis, invocation

I'm new to C# programming and wanted to know what I'm doing wrong here. This script has been working fine for the past 2 weeks but now throws a invocation error message. Can anyone shed any light ?

The script runs from my local computer and connects to the database on a server.

Thanks
Bal

```
public void Main()
{
    string SqlConn = Dts.Variables["User::SQLConn"].Value.ToString();
    string StartDate = Dts.Variables["PeriodStart"].Value.ToString();
    string EndDate = Dts.Variables["PeriodEnd"].Value.ToString();

    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConn);
    SqlCommand TraderQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Code] FROM [dbo].[Trader] ORDER BY [Code]", Conn);
    DataTable TraderTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(TraderQuery);
    adapter.Fill(TraderTable);

    // Execute SQL Query
    foreach (DataRow row in TraderTable.Rows)
    {
        string Trader = row["Code"].ToString();

        string VolumeRebateQuery = (
            "CREATE TABLE STA_VolumeRebate " +
            "(" +
             "Rank int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY," +
             "TraderId varchar(100) NOT NULL," +
             "Market varchar(10)," +
             "Product varchar(30)," +
             "Lots Float," +
             "LotsOfHigherOrder Float" +
            ")" +

            "DECLARE @TraderName VARCHAR(10) " +
            "DECLARE @StartDate DATE " +
            "DECLARE @EndDate DATE " +

            "SET @TraderName = '" + Trader + "' " +
            "SET @StartDate = '" + StartDate + "'" +
            "SET @EndDate = '" + EndDate + "'" +

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ";WITH MarketTotals AS (SELECT Trader.Code AS 'TraderId', MarketGrouping.Name AS 'Market', SUM(Trades.BuyQuantity + Trades.SellQuantity) AS 'Lots' " +

            "FROM [dbo].[Trades] JOIN " +
            "dbo.Account ON Trades.Account = Account.Id JOIN " +
            "dbo.Trader ON Account.TraderId = Trader.Id JOIN " +
            "dbo.Market ON Trades.Market = Market.Id JOIN " +
            "dbo.MarketGrouping ON Market.MarketGrouping = MarketGrouping.Id " +

            "WHERE Trader.Code = @TraderName AND Trades.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate " +
            "AND Trades.Account NOT IN (1475) AND Trades.ExchangeFeeCurrency+Trades.ClearingFee<>0 " +

            "GROUP BY  Trader.Code, MarketGrouping.Name), " +

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            "TraderTotals AS (SELECT Trader.Code AS 'TraderId', MarketGrouping.Name AS 'Market', ProductGrouping.Code AS 'Product', SUM(Trades.BuyQuantity + Trades.SellQuantity) AS 'Lots' " +

            "FROM [dbo].[Trades] JOIN " +
            "dbo.Account ON Trades.Account = Account.Id JOIN " +
            "dbo.Trader ON Account.TraderId = Trader.Id JOIN " +
            "dbo.Market ON Trades.Market = Market.Id JOIN " +
            "dbo.MarketGrouping ON Market.MarketGrouping = MarketGrouping.Id JOIN " +
            "dbo.ProductDetails ON Trades.Product = ProductDetails.Id JOIN " +
            "dbo.ProductGrouping ON ProductDetails.ProductId = ProductGrouping.Id " +

            "WHERE Trader.Code = @TraderName AND Trades.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate " +
            "AND Trades.Account NOT IN (1475) AND Trades.ExchangeFeeCurrency+Trades.ClearingFee<>0 " +

            "GROUP BY  Trader.Code, MarketGrouping.Name, ProductGrouping.Code), " +
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            "TempTBL AS (SELECT TraderTotals.*, MarketTotals.Lots AS 'LotsOfHigherOrder' " +
            "FROM TraderTotals JOIN " +
            "MarketTotals ON TraderTotals.Market = MarketTotals.Market), " +

            "TempTBL2 AS (select TraderId,Market, Product, Lots,LotsOfHigherOrder, " +
            "CASE WHEN TempTBL.Market IN ('CBOT','CME','COMEX','NYMEX') THEN 'CME' " +
            "     WHEN TempTBL.Market IN ('LIFFE','LCP') THEN 'LIFFE' ELSE TempTBL.Market END AS 'MarketGrouping' " +
            "from TempTBL), " +

            "TempTBL3 AS (select TraderId,MarketGrouping, SUM(Lots) AS 'LotsOfHigherOrder' " +
            "from TempTBL2 " +
            "GROUP BY TraderId,MarketGrouping), " +

            "FinalTBL AS (SELECT TempTBL2.TraderId, TempTBL2.Market, TempTBL2.Product, TempTBL2.Lots, TempTBL3.LotsOfHigherOrder " +
            "FROM TempTBL2 LEFT JOIN " +
            "TempTBL3 ON TempTBL3.MarketGrouping = TempTBL2.MarketGrouping) " +

            "SELECT TraderId, Market, Product, Lots, LotsOfHigherOrder " +
            "INTO STG_VolumeRebate " +
            "FROM FinalTBL " +
            "ORDER BY LotsOfHigherOrder DESC, Lots DESC " +

            "INSERT INTO dbo.STA_VolumeRebate (TraderId, Market, Product, Lots, LotsOfHigherOrder) " +
            "SELECT TraderId, Market, Product, Lots, LotsOfHigherOrder " +
            "FROM STG_VolumeRebate " +
            "WHERE Market = 'ICE OTC' " +
            "ORDER BY LotsOfHigherOrder DESC, Lots DESC " +

            "INSERT INTO dbo.STA_VolumeRebate (TraderId, Market, Product, Lots, LotsOfHigherOrder) " +
            "SELECT TraderId, Market, Product, Lots, LotsOfHigherOrder " +
            "FROM STG_VolumeRebate " +
            "WHERE Market <> 'ICE OTC' " +
            "ORDER BY LotsOfHigherOrder DESC, Lots DESC " +


            "INSERT INTO dbo.VolumeRebate " +
            "SELECT [Rank]" +
                  ",[TraderId]" +
                  ",[Market]" +
                  ",[Product]" +
                  ",[Lots]" +
                  ",[LotsOfHigherOrder]" +
                  ",(SELECT SUM(Lots) FROM dbo.STA_VolumeRebate) - SUM([Lots]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [TraderId] " +
                  "ORDER BY [Rank] " +
                  "RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 'LotsOfHigherOrder' " +
             " FROM dbo.STA_VolumeRebate" +
             " ORDER BY [Rank]" +
              "DROP TABLE STG_VolumeRebate DROP TABLE STA_VolumeRebate");

        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(VolumeRebateQuery);
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\QueryOutput.txt", VolumeRebateQuery);

        SqlCommand VolumeRebateExecute = new SqlCommand(VolumeRebateQuery, Conn);
        VolumeRebateExecute.Connection.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Trying to execute query for Trader " + Trader + " now");
        VolumeRebateExecute.ExecuteNonQuery();
        VolumeRebateExecute.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Include the *actual* exception and stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Do you have a new trader named `O'Brien`? All joking aside, an apostrophe in the name would kill the query - try switching to parameters and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Another suggestion: consider pulling those lump of `create .. insert .. select` queries in a stored procedure for better efficiency.

Comment: @ D'Stanley the Trader codes are all letters but good pint for me to look out for. @Rahul Good Point I will try to put into a Stored Procedure see if that helps.

Comment: @ Daniel Kelley the error  is "DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code Project name: ST_blahblahblah" Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: right so I now have that query in a stored procedure however it still fails. Could it be a timeout error from SSIS side (I have tried setting the SQL Timeout to zero and still get an error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ! there is a timeout set on ADO Connections to 30 seconds and the one account took longer than this. I added the below line to resolve the problem ! Thanks All for suggestions and improving my code ! Bal

```
                 "VolumeRebateExecute.CommandTimeout = 120;"
```